# Где можно найти качественный компилятор LISP?

Tags: lisp

Здравствуйте, товарищи! Решил я, значит, на LISP пописать. Язык интересный, весёлый, мощный. Код запускаю при помощи LispWorks. Возник такой вопрос: можно ли где найти компилятор кода LISP в исполняемый файл? Под Windows, Linux и/или OS X?

Comment: Чем вам не подходит вариант `интерпретатор (экзешка) + файлы скриптов`?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Да просто как-то привычнее, когда можно на выходе тот же exe получить) Вот я и интересуюсь, можно ли где достать такую вразумительную вещь) (Я видел один компилятор, но он выдал файл в 31 Мб с кодом (print (+ 2 3)), мне это немного не понравилось хД)

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос на enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521477/what-is-the-best-scheme-interpreter-or-compiler

Comment: Есть [tag:clojure], который собирается в `.class` или `.jar`-файлы под JVM (Java Virtual Machine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вопрос не имеет ответа в силу того что LISP - симейство языков.

**Диалекты LISP**

- CommonLisp
- Scheme
- Elisp (Emacs Lisp)
- AutoLisp (AutoCAD Lisp)

**Реализации Common Lisp**

- http://sbcl.org/
- http://www.lispworks.com/
- https://www.gnu.org/software/gcl/
- https://clisp.sourceforge.io/

Посмотрите проект Roswell , он  облегчит вам установку.

Используя пакет **buildspp** для **SBCL** можно создать экзешник:

```
buildapp --eval '(defun main (argv) (write-line "Hello, world"))' --entry main --output hello
```

**Сылки**

- https://github.com/roswell/roswell
- https://www.cliki.net/Creating%20Executables
- https://www.cliki.net/Common+Lisp+implementation

Comment: Спасибо огромное!